# Can you prevent a function from executing inside a dictionary mapping in python?

Tags: python, function, dictionary

When mapping functions to a dictionary, python automatically executes the function before the key is called. Can this be prevented? 
Example:

```
def testfunc():
    print 'Executed'

testdict = { '1': testfunc(),}
>>>EXECUTED
```

If not, is there a better way to do this? Would this be a call for decorators or something?

Comment: Omit the function call operator, the `()`, so `'1': testfunc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you may prevent the execution pf method, by not calling it,menas by not providing the parentheses.
And whenever you want to call the method you can,see below:

```
def testfunc():
    print 'Executed'
testdict = {'1': testfunc,}
testdict['1']()
Executed
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you are creating the dictionary maps the return value of `testfunc()` to the key `'1'`. In order to know the return value, the function has to be executed first. If you are simply trying to save the function in the dictionary, do:

```
testdict = {'1': testfunc,}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply, remove the parentheses after the function's name when mapping:

```
testdict = {'1': testfunc,} # remove the parentheses, in order to save the function, 
                            # not its return value
```

& to call it:

```
testdict['1']()
```

Comment: How would you handle this is you wanted to pass a param with the function?